# In gamesalad actor moves out of the screen on x-axis

Tags: iphone, ios

In gamesalad framework I am creating a game in which I have an actor which only moves on x-axis on touch is pressed.  But when I move it to x-axis the actor goes away out of the range of the screen. Let me clarify that I am new to gamesalad framework.

plz help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reading this in two different ways:

1 - when you press your touch controls the actor disappears from the screen
2 - when you press the touch control the actor moves along the x-axis and out of the screen

For the sake of argument I'm going to assume that we're talking about number two.

What you'll need to do is restrict the actors movement to the boundaries of the current screen.  You can do this is two ways with Gamesalad

1 - create an invisible barrier for your actor to collide against
2 - use a behaviour to prevent your actor from going beyond the screen boundary

I'll explain both:

1, Invisible barriers
What you'll do is create a new actor, and set it to collide with the actor that your controlling.  You'll create a few instances of this actor to create a walled area for your actor.  Although this works, it's a little cludgy and using additional actors in a scene take a little performance away from your application.

2, using a behaviour
In my opinion the better way is to use the given behaviours in Gamesalad itself.
To stop the player actor from moving off screen you can use a combination of Rules and the Constrain Attribute behaviour to achieve this.

The first thing to know is your screen size; for an iPad I believe it's 1074 along the x-axis.

So to stop the actor moving off either side of the screen you'll need to do the following:

Open up the player actor
the click on the "Create Rule" button on the top right.
A new rule window will appear, but default the first dropdown will say "Actor receives event" change this to "Attribute".

Next select the attribute to use the rule against, since we're interested in the x-axis we'll want to query that player attribute which will be:

(also known as self) > Position > X

Select the greater than symbol (">") and then enter the maximum width of the screen minus whatever border value you want, so I'll use 1014 (1024 - 10).

Find and drag the Constrain Attribute behaviour into your rule a set the actors X position to 1014.

This will stop the actor from going beyond one side of the screen, now copy the rule and amend the settings to that if the actor goes less than, say 10, it will constrain the actors X position to 10.

I'd post an image, but alas my Karma isn't large enough right now!  Hence the large explanation!

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It is way easier than that.

In top of the Gamesalad Creator there is a play button, which you probably know, displays your progress. To the left of this button there is a button that looks like a little video camera, it changes the camera settings. So what you first have to do is click the camera button, then the rectangular camera screen will show itself as marked. In the center of each of the sides of the highlighted rectangular which is the camera screen, sits 1 little grey rectangular. Each of these needs to be pulled to the center of the camera view so that you get a little grey "cross" in the center and from the center to the boarder there will now be this highlighted color.

Second and last step is easy, just go under your character and in (type or drag in a behavior block) you type control camera... or drag the control camera block, which as by the type box is statet possible.

Since Gamesalad only can have one camera at a time, and you character is the only one with the control camera option applied it will follow him and only him. Wherever your character starts on the screen, the camera will follow it when it passes through the center of the screen. You may know this from Super Mario Bros. Where you start of a little to the left and walk right and the second Mario enters the center of the screen, the camera follows him from then on.

Hope this helps... :